# "login failed" while Importing Data using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to import an Excel file into SQL Server 2016 using a SQL Server Management Studio remote client.  When I run the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, I can successfully define the Excel file as the source but I get a "login failed" error when defining the destination.

Here are the Destination parameters I'm using:

- Destination: SQL Server Native Client 11.0
- Server name:  MyServerAddress, Port
- Authentication:  Use SQL Server authentication
- Username:  MyDatabaseUsername

The error I get when I click "Next" in the Wizard is:

> login failed for user 'MyDatabaseUsername'. (SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

I'm sure I'm providing a valid username and password for my destination database.

Any idea why I'm getting a "login failed" error?

Comment: You're getting a login failed because the login failed :) either you've made a mistake with the username/password, if that user isn't configured correctly in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to need a little more than that.  I've been able to successfully build tables and views as that user, which BTW has db_owner and db_datawriter roles.  Logins don't fail for this user under other circumstances.

Comment: But we can't give you any more than that because we don't know your system.

Comment: If we are to read this literally, in your destination parameters provided above, password is not listed as a parameter. So, are you sure you are providing a password? Because if not, well... you get the idea.

Comment: Password is not one of the fields that is shown when I select "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" as the Destination.  However, password is saved as part of the SSMS connection.  I assumed that the password was being supplied by the connection as I am never prompted for it.  That could be the problem but I'm not sure how to resolve!!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out ... The SSMS Import and Export Wizard dialog box was sized in a way that hid the password field (plus a couple of other fields).  I had no idea that the dialog box needed to be resized, except I just by chance pulled on one of the edges of the dialog to resize it and wham-o ... the extra fields appeared out of nowhere.

Thanks to robbpriestley for giving me a clue and making me think!